# Remove blank space in dataTable primefaces

Tags: css, primefaces

I have a simple primefaces DataTable with Expansion row that display some data.

How can I remove the blank space between the parent table and the nested one ?(as shown in the image below) ?

[image]

I have tried adding `tableStyle="table-layout:auto;width:100%;left-padding:0px"` to my dataTable but no result. Can you please help me to resolve this little issue ?

FYI : I am using Primefaces 5.1

Thanks,

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Thansk for your feedback. I've mentioned above my current code that didn't work : tableStyle="table-layout:auto;width:100%;left-padding:0px".

Comment: Please post your minimal JSF XHTML, that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATED***

Try changing the style of the MAIN table (not the nested table):

```
tableStyle="padding:0;"
```

If that takes away the padding for the nested table, then change the padding for the main table back to an acceptable value (lets assume 4), and then on the nested table try:

```
tableStyle="margin:-4px;"
```

...and see if that does it for you.

It looks like the default padding is that the -left,-right is one value, and -top,-bottom is a different value.  If so just try to replicate those values as negative numbers using margin- on the inner table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added border-collapse: collapse; to my tablestyle and still the same behavior. I also don't have any specific css used as The default css used is generated b primefaces theme.

Comment: Modified my answer.  Also, if you're doing cross browser development, you might want to get in the habit of adding a normalize style-sheet to your html which will solve a lot of cross-browser layout issues.

Comment: Perfect !!!!! That's resolves my issue. Thank so so so much for your precious help. Marked as resolved . have a nice day